pycryptodome do not install correctly with pip
I am currently writing a code in python that is need of "pycryptodome". At the start of the code I import the Cryptodome.Cipher and i have installed pycryptodome with the help of pip. However, i still get this message: Import "Cryptodome.Cipher" could not be resolved. I have tried to understand where i have went wrong but know i am stuck.
Here is an example code:
from insecure_hash import hash_string
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

def test(message):
    # Your solution
    key = "Arandomkey123456" # a key 16 bytes
    cipher = AES.new(key)
    result = cipher.encrypt(hashValue)
    result = result + key
    return result

This is what i get in the terminal after doing tests: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cryptodome'

Isn't the module called Crypto?
